# How to get touch coordinates in hammerjs?

Tags: javascript, typescript, hammer.js

Can anybody tell me how to get touch coordinates in hammerjs?
Following code is giving error:

```
hammerEvent.on('pan', (ev) => {
  console.log('x, y: ', ev.clientX, ev.clientY);
}
```

Comment: try ev.deltaX, ev.deltaY

Comment: @AhbapAldirmaz They are not touch coordinates.

Comment: Inside the ev object there is a PointerEvent named changedPointers. There are clientX and clientY values. 
ev.changedPointers[0].clientX,
ev.changedPointers[0].clientY,
Look at this.

Comment: Yes but only one touch coordinate is coming. You touch screen with four fingers than also length of changedPointers is 1 only. I think its a bug.

Comment: Any luck for this?
ev.changedPointers[0].clientX, ev.changedPointers[0].clientY, values of these to properties jump sometimes. Like 1 instance it was 325...326...327...410
Which property gives the exact cords?