# How to get rotation angle in ionic gesture API?

Tags: angular, ionic-framework

I'm working on canvas and was handling gesture events with hammerjs. But there I was facing an issue which I already asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64771838/how-to-get-touch-coordinates-in-hammerjs) and other places but nobody responded. So now I'm working with ionic gestures but there also I can't find rotation angle property. Can anybody help me with that?

Here's the code:

```
ngAfterViewInit() {
      const gesture: Gesture = this.gestureCtrl.create({
      el: this.transCanvasElement,
      gestureName: 'rotate',
      onStart: ev => this.onStartHandler(ev)
    }, true);
    gesture.enable();
}
onStartHandler(ev) {
    console.log('ionic gesture ev angle: ', ev.rotation); // ev.rotation is undefined
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Meaning of `this` in JS depends on the scope. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20279484/6513921) for more info. You could either bind `this` to the callback or make it an arrow function.

Try the following

**Option 1: bind `this`**

```js
ngAfterViewInit() {
  const gesture: Gesture = this.gestureCtrl.create({
    el: this.transCanvasElement,
    gestureName: 'rotate',
    onStart: this.onStartHandler.bind(this)  // <-- bind `this` to the callback
  }, true);
  gesture.enable();
}

onStartHandler(ev) {
  console.log('ionic gesture ev angle: ', ev.rotation);
}
```

**Option 2: arrow function**

```js
ngAfterViewInit() {
  const gesture: Gesture = this.gestureCtrl.create({
    el: this.transCanvasElement,
    gestureName: 'rotate',
    onStart: ev => this.onStartHandler(ev)
  }, true);
  gesture.enable();
}

onStartHandler = (ev) => {                           // <-- arrow function
  console.log('ionic gesture ev angle: ', ev.rotation);
}
```

Comment: Option 1 is giving an error bind() method doesn't exist on type void and Option 2 giving the same result as before. ev.rotation is still undefined.

Comment: Yes the arrow notation isn't required in option. I've updated the answer. Regarding error in option 2, please check if `rotation` property is actually available in `ev` variable. Try to print only `ev` to verify.

Comment: No there's no rotation property. That's why I asked this question if anybody could help me find it in nested objects of ev. Its strange to not have rotation property in gesture API.